# How to code the auto& in a if else or switch case format?

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, switch-statement, auto

I used to have a code to extract certain part

```
auto& c = m_matrix[name];
....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
```

now I have to use a if/else or switch case for m_matrix options like the following statement:

```
switch input{
  case 1:
     auto& c = A[name];
  case 2:
     auto& c = B[name];
}
....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
```

A and B have the same type of elements. However, this is wrong as it will show that the definition of c is duplicated. At the same time, I can't declare auto& c; before switch/case as well like the following:

```
auto& c;
switch input {
   case 1:
      c = A[name];
   case 2:
      c = B[name];
}

....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Update: CinCout - Reinstate Monica kindly offers a solution of

```
switch input {
   case 1:{
      auto& c = A[name];
      ....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
   }
   case 2:{
      auto& c = B[name];
      ....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
   }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the repetitive code in each case? Thanks

Comment: Do the matrix expressions or their elements all have the same type, or do the types vary?

Comment: Also, your question will get more attention with a language tag. This looks like C++, except for the "end"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The elements all have the same type.

Comment: *"I can't declare auto& c; before switch/case as well."* Definitely not as a *reference*, but you can certainly do it as a variable or a pointer.

Comment: How should I do it? I used to declare the type std::map<soba::Date, double>> c; but the result is wrong

Comment: You need to show how `A` and `B` are declared.

Comment: std::map<std::string, std::map<soba::Date, double>> A,B

Comment: Why don't you move your `switch` in a method that returns `std::map<soba::Date, double>&`? Will make life easier.

Comment: Do you mean declare std::map<soba::Date, double>&c, and then define c in the switch statement?

Comment: No, write a method that finds and returns `c` as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just give each `case` a scope of its own, effectively giving each `c` a local scope:

```
switch input
{
  case 1:
  {
     auto& c = A[name];
     …
     break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
     auto& c = B[name];
     …
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a relatively large block of code outside switch to work with too. Do I need to repeat the same code (...) in each scope ever time. Is there any other more efficient way? It seems the code will still be wrong if I put the code with c outside of switch box.

Comment: auto& c = A[name]; or auto& c = B[name]; is not the same. But the rest of code ... using c will be the same.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Please edit your question to post relevant code

Comment: Ok just put it in the question.

Comment: @hibernateisland See my comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function or lambda:

```
auto get_c = [&] -> decltype(A[name])& {
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        return A[name];
    case 2:
        return B[name];
    }
    return A[name];    // default case
};
auto& c = getC();
....large block of code with using c in the calculation...
```